# Is the following subset of $F^n$ closed under addition and scalar multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Is the following subset of $F^n$ closed under addition and scalar multiplication?
$$W=\{(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)\in F^n:a_1+a_2+...+a_n=1\}$$

I think it is not, for the following reasons:

Let there be two examples of $W$:
$$W_1=\{(b_1,b_2,...,b_n)\in F^n:b_1+b_2+...+b_n=1\}$$
$$W_2=\{(c_1,c_2,...,c_n)\in F^n:c_1+c_2+...+c_n=1\}$$
Checking for closure under addition:
$$W_1+W_2=(b_1+c_1,b_2+c_2,...,b_n+c_n)$$
$$b_1+c_1+b_2+c_2+...+b_n+c_n=2$$
Therefore, $W$ is not closed under addition. Now, checking for closure under scalar multiplication:
$$cW=\{(ca_1,ca_2,...,ca_n)\}$$
Where $c$ is some arbitrary constant such that $c\in F$.
$$ca_1+ca_2+...+ca_n=c$$
Therefore, $W$ is not closed under scalar multiplication.

This question popped up in my mind when I was trying to figure out whether $W$ is a subspace of $F^n$ or not, and I know that the easiest test here is to simply check for the $0$ vector, which does not belong to $W$ and therefore, it is not a subspace of $F^n$, but I wanted to try out the two other tests as well, but wasn't sure how to go about it.

For context, I am self-studying Linear Algebra and I have not taken any official courses on the subject yet. Also, I am utilizing Linear Algebra by Stephen H. Friedberg (textbook), which is where I picked up the question from - Chapter 1: Vector Spaces, Subsection 1.3: Subspaces Exercise 10.

Comment: "Let there be two subsets..." That is not sensical. They aren't "two subsets", they are the same subset and they are all equql to $W$. Also "closure under addition" is about taking two elements from one set, and seeing of the sum is in the same set. You do jot check closure under addition by taking what are outatively two sets and adding the sets. And your description of what "$W_1+W_2$" would be is patently incorrect. This is a mess of misunderstood notions and half-understood notation and proof arguments.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I am new to Linear Algebra, and I am self-studying it, so it would be really helpful if you could also please correct my errors or at least point me towards resources from where I could learn about my errors, thank you!

Comment: "I am new to Linear Algebra and am self-studying it." Was I supposed to just know that, guess that, or were you expecting me to read your mind? (Sorry, the Government doesn't like it when I read minds without a warrant). This is context and information that you should put in your question, if you want answers that will be useful to you. As it was, you wasted my time and the time of others who reply in a way that is useless to you, because you did not bother to tell us what *would* be useful to you.

Comment: The level of your question is indistinguishable from one from someone who is taking an introductory class in Linear Algebra, and who will be following a particular textbook. You provide **no** information to distinguish you from someone taking a class. I have time to explain things to people, what I don't have time for is to spend time and effort providing an answer in the wrong context because the person asking the question could not be bothered to tell us (i) their situation; (ii) their resources. You are "self-studying", but you don't tell us your book. **You** are wasting people's time.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Alright, I realize my mistake, and I apologize for the errors. For further information, yes, I am self-studying the subject, and the textbook I am using is Linear Algebra by Stephen H. Friedberg.

Comment: The information needs to be in the post itself, not buried in the comments. You should say which part of the text you are taking your question from, so people know what you have already looked at/know and what you don't.

Comment: @noobanomaly: Hi, my post does not answer your question? Please tell me (now that your question is much clearer with Arturo's correction) how I can improve my answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

Why two sets of $F^n$? In order to use the well-known characterization of vector subspace you need to see for $W\subseteq F^n$ is vector subspace if

- $W\not=\emptyset$, for example you can see if $0_{F^{n}}\in W$.
- To show if you take two vector in $W$ for example $a,b$, then $a+b\in W$.
- To show if you take a scalar $\alpha$ in the field and a vector $b$ in $W$, then $\alpha b\in W$

Now, notice that if $a$ is a vector in $W$, then satisfy $\sum_{j}a_j=1$ and if you take a vector $b$ in $W$, then it vector satisfy $\sum_{j}b_j =1$, but in order that $a+b\in W$ it new vector need to satisfy $\sum_{j}(a_j+b_j)=1$ but it is not true, because $\sum_{j}(a_j+b_j)=\sum_{j}a_j +\sum_{j}b_j=1+1=2\not=1$. Hence $W$ is not closed under the addition of vectors. Similar with the other condition.